# Nginx not getting web request

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have a rails app that is serving assets to port 80 but the rails app itself is running on 3000. I was using nginx to proxy requests from a custom host on port 3000 to 80 to solve this, which was working great but I also need wildcard dns for my app.

I installed `echoipdns` for wildcard dns:
https://github.com/zapty/echoipdns

Which was working at first, but I turned my computer off (Ubuntu 14.04) and turned it back on and didn't have internet access (was able to ping external ip's just not any domains)

Figured out that /etc/resolv.conf was set to `nameserver 127.0.0.1` which is what echoipdns changes to get it to work with it's own dns.

I fixed the internet problem by switching /etc/resolv.conf back to `nameserver 127.0.1.1` so that dnsmasq is the dns server, and found that I can explicitly tell echoipdns to route all non local requests to another dns server like this: `sudo echoipdns development -f 127.0.1.1` which will route all requests that end it `development` to it's own dns (to return an A record with the correct host in it) and all other requests to 127.0.1.1 for dnsmasq to handle.

echoipdns and the internet is working but... Nginx isn't serving anything.

I uninstalled and reinstalled nginx, it has the default virtualhost right now but going to `localhost` doesn't serve the nginx index.html, it doesn't serve anything, not even a "bad gateway". I'm not getting anything in the error or access logs, so it's gotta be a network issue of some sort.

I'm not sure where to start with this problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what your `/etc/hosts` says? Are localhost still pointing to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, I also have a custom host set for the proxy: `127.0.0.1 dev`

Comment: post your nginx configuration file to investigate further.

Comment: Nginx configs (including vhost) are completely stock right now. I completely removed nginx and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with `iptables`

I ran the commands under "FLUSH ALL RULES, ERASE NON-DEFAULT CHAINS" here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13755/how-to-reset-all-iptables-settings

and that fixed it.

Echoipdns setup a prerouting rule to route requests from port 80 to 20559 and port 443 to 20558

Resetting these rules made the nginx default page come right up.